# Want to get the html for pdf template from PDF manager(Sugar 7.6)

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

I want to get the html of pdf manager using bean. I know how to get the html for email template but unable to get the html for pdf template which u build in pdf manager.

```
    $template = new EmailTemplate();
    $template->retrieve_by_string_fields(array(‘name’ => $template_name,’type’=>’email’));
    $html=$template->body_html;
```

How can i achieve the same functionality when i want to get the html template from pdf manager?

Answer (score 0):

The retrieve_by_string_fields function is deprecated as of 7.6 as per [this](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Data_Framework/Models/SugarBean/#Retrieving_a_Bean_by_Unique_Field), so you might want to consider using [SugarQuery](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Data_Framework/Database/SugarQuery/index.html) instead. There's no "type" field in the PDF Manager, so I've just gone with the name attribute from your code. This should provide you with an array of records matching the condition.

```
require_once("include/SugarQuery/SugarQuery.php");
$sugarQuery = new SugarQuery();
$sugarQuery->select("body_html");
$sugarQuery->from(BeanFactory::newBean('PdfManager'));
$sugarQuery->where()->equals("name", $template_name);
$html = $sugarQuery->execute();
```